# Hidden WebView to PDF - result is blank?

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview

Basically the aim is to generate a PDF report that is then later attached to an email and sent automatically (I'm using Mailgun for this side which is all working fine) when a user hits submit, without the PDF being shown or the print dialog appearing.

This is the code I have so far, which just generates a blank PDF. Because I am using this for commercial use, I'm unable to use libraries such as iText for this.

```
    WebView web = new WebView(c); // c is context, provided when method called
    web.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", pdfTemplate, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    PrintAttributes.Builder b = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
            .setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR)
            .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
            .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
            .setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("1", "label", 300, 300));
    PrintedPdfDocument doco = new PrintedPdfDocument(c, b.build());
    PdfDocument.Page p = doco.startPage(1);
    web.draw(p.getCanvas());
    doco.finishPage(p);
```

What can I do to make this work without the user seeing anything?

Comment: "Because I am using this for commercial use, I'm unable to use libraries such as iText for this" -- iText offers [commercial licensing](https://itextpdf.com/Pricing). A variety of other libraries and services show up for a search on `android library generate pdf` on a major search engine. With regards to your problem, `WebView` loads its content on a background thread (so you are trying to print too early). Plus, in your case, it would be far simpler to just package a PDF file in assets, rather than package HTML and try to generate a PDF.

Comment: I take your point however there are various reasons why we are not in a position to use a paid commercial license.

Is there any way I can wait for the WebView to be loaded and then trigger the PDF code?

If I were to package a PDF in assets, how would I go about editing the content - the PDF contents will change each time, as it'll be populated with data from the application, which previously I was using string.replace to replace placeholders of.

Comment: " Is there any way I can wait for the WebView to be loaded and then trigger the PDF code?" -- depending on your HTML, the `WebViewClient` approach outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46525763/115145) should work. That doesn't handle deliberately asynchronous work (e.g., AJAX). "how would I go about editing the content" -- whoops, sorry, I misread the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom WebViewClient and override the "onPageFinished" method like this:

```
class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        //do your pdf logic
    }
}
```

then just call this before you load the URL:

```
web.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

Comment: Thanks - created it, moved all the PDF and email logic over, the code has triggered, but it's unfortunately still blank.
Edit: I did make sure to load the URL after setting the client.